# How to get gcc to compile 16-bit unicode strings

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, unicode-literals

So I'm trying to compile this project : https://github.com/dmitrystu/libusb_stm32 with Segger Embedded studio which uses gcc.  The process is choking on this error :

```
pasting formed 'u"Open source USB stack for STM32"', an invalid preprocessing token
```

which is caused by this line :

```
static const struct usb_string_descriptor manuf_desc_en = USB_STRING_DESC("Open source USB stack for STM32");
```

So `USB_STRING_DESC` is a macro :

```
#define USB_STRING_DESC(s)         {.bLength = sizeof(CAT(u,s)),.bDescriptorType = USB_DTYPE_STRING,.wString = {CAT(u,s)}}
```

And `CAT` is a macro `CAT(x,y) x##y`.  The intent must be to convert a string of type 8-bit `char` into a 16-bit Unicode type but the compiler doesn't like it.  Is there some `#include` or compiler setting that may be missing that I have to add here?  Clearly the author of this code expects it to work so there must be some fault in my setup.

Also I'm not clear on how the `sizeof()` operation is supposed to work here.  As I understand it there is no way to get the length of a string at compile time so that operation will always return the size of a pointer.

Comment: What version of gcc are you using, with what options? The `u"literal"` syntax was introduced in C11. Use `-std=c11` or `-std=gnu11` if necessary (recent versions of gcc default to `-std=gnu11`).

Comment: `sizeof` applied to a string *literal* gives the size of the corresponding array. Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](https://www.c-faq.com/).

Answer (score 1):

In response to Keith's question, the gcc version is 4.2.1.  Poking around the compiler settings the default option is the C99 standard, when I changed it to C11 everything compiled just fine.  Thanks!